# Return specific RestTemplate bean, how?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans, resttemplate

I want to load an SSL certificate into a resttemplate and use it. But the project I'm working on already has a resttemplate bean that's used in different parts of the project. I want a resttemplate with a specific ssl cert loaded that I want to use in a specific part of the app. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you have already that 2nd `RestTemplate`?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create another `RestTemplate` bean:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate sslCertRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = // create your specific rest template
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

You can inject this `sslCertRestTemplate` using the `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Qualifier("sslCertRestTemplate")
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```